# Where can I find a table of the exponents of the sporadic groups?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, sporadic-groups, monster

Is there a table showing Sporadic Groups and their exponents, and, perhaps, other basic properties.
In particular, I'm interested in what the exponent of the Monster Group is. (Obviously the order is well publicised, but not the exponent, as far as I can tell.)
Thanks!

Comment: This information can be calculated easily  from the printed character tables in the ATLAS of Finite Groups (which include orders of elements in conjugacy classes) or, perhaps more conveniently, using the same information online via GAP or Magma. From there you can just load the character table from the library and calcualte the lcm of the orders of the elements.

Comment: I had a quick look at the character table of the Monster in the Atlas, and its exponent appears to be $32.27.25.7.11.13.17.19.23.29.31.47.59.71$.

Comment: Or, using the version of the ATLAS tables in Gap's character table library, `Exponent(CharacterTable("F1"));` (returns `1165654792878376600800`) for the exponent of the Monster.

Comment: Oh dear, I missed out the factor 41 in my previous comment! Well I said it was a quick look!

Comment: Hi chaps, thanks, I really appreciate your answers :)
For the Monster the answer is 1165654792878376600800, which is amazing.
Does anyone know of an existing table online showing the exponents of all the sporadic groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments,
This information can be calculated easily from the printed character tables in the ATLAS of Finite Groups (which include orders of elements in conjugacy classes) or, perhaps more conveniently, using the same information online via GAP or Magma. From there you can just load the character table from the library and calculate the lcm of the orders of the elements.
I had a quick look at the character table of the Monster in the Atlas, and its exponent appears to be 32.27.25.7.11.13.17.19.23.29.31.47.59.71.41
 - Derek Holt

Or, using the version of the ATLAS tables in Gap's character table library, Exponent(CharacterTable("F1")); (returns 1165654792878376600800) for the exponent of the Monster.
 – Gro-Tsen

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't find an online table of exponents for sporadic groups, so I used GAP to produce one:

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{Group}&&\mathbf{Exponent}&&\mathbf{Factorization}\\
M_{11}&&1320&&2^3\cdot3\cdot5\cdot11\\
M_{12}&&1320&&2^3\cdot3\cdot5\cdot11\\
J_1&&43890&&2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot19\\
M_{22}&&9240&&2^3\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\\
J_2&&840&&2^3\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\\
M_{23}&&212520&&2^3\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot23\\
HS&&9240&&2^3\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\\
J_3&&116280&&2^3\cdot3^2\cdot5\cdot17\cdot19\\
M_{24}&&212520&&2^3\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot23\\
McL&&27720&&2^3\cdot3^2\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\\
He&&14280&&2^3\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot17\\
Ru&&633360&&2^4\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot13\cdot29\\
Suz&&360360&&2^3\cdot3^2\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\\
O'N&&10884720&&2^4\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot19\cdot31\\
Co_3&&637560&&2^3\cdot3^2\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot23\\
Co_2&&1275120&&2^4\cdot3^2\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot23\\
Fi_{22}&&720720&&2^4\cdot3^2\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\\
HN&&2633400&&2^3\cdot3^2\cdot5^2\cdot7\cdot11\cdot19\\
Ly&&10651271400&&2^3\cdot3^2\cdot5^2\cdot7\cdot11\cdot31\cdot37\cdot67\\
Th&&57886920&&2^3\cdot3^3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot13\cdot19\cdot31\\
Fi_{23}&&845404560&&2^4\cdot3^3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot23\\
Co_1&&16576560&&2^4\cdot3^2\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot23\\
J_4&&607938537360&&2^4\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot23\cdot29\cdot31\cdot37\cdot43\\
F_{3+}&&24516732240&&2^4\cdot3^3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot23\cdot29\\
B&&234033344344800&&2^5\cdot3^3\cdot5^2\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19\cdot23\cdot31\cdot47\\
M&&1165654792878376600800&&2^5\cdot3^3\cdot5^2\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19\cdot23\\
&&&&\cdot29\cdot31\cdot41\cdot47\cdot59\cdot71\\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: It would be more intuitive if you also paste the prime decomposition of these numbers.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thanks for adding the factoring and the nice layout. It's much better than what I posted. You should have posted it as your own answer and gotten the points.

Comment: It wasn’t me, @StevenStadnicki deserves the credit. All I did was correct the table header from “Order” to “Exponent”.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Sorry for not paying more attention to the edit history. Thank you for your improvements! Your edit comment says that I had a typo. What was it?

Comment: You didn't have a typo — my first edit did (an incorrect factorization), and I made a second edit to fix my mistake but they may have been folded into one. And you're very welcome!